# Why my Duplex Stream is not emitting an 'end' event?

Tags: node.js

I have this stream:

```
import * as stream from "stream";

export default class FileStream extends stream.Duplex {
    private callbackNotCalled = true;
    private canWrite = true;

    constructor(options: any) {
        super(options);
    }

    write(chunk: Buffer): any {
        if (this.callbackNotCalled) {
            this.emit('readytoread', this);
            this.callbackNotCalled = false;
        }

        this.push(chunk);

        if (this.closed) {
            this.push(null);
            this.canWrite = false;
        }

        return this.canWrite;
    }
    
    _read() {}
}
```

There's data from a socket piped into it. Sometime later, I use the stream to read data from it:

```
    public async createFile(filePath: string, fileStream: FileStream): Promise<stream.Writable> {
        let j = 0;
        let buffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
        let resultBuffer = Buffer.alloc(0);
        let bufferSizeMax = 98304; //25e+6;
        let currentBufferSize = 0;

        let partNum = 0;

        fileStream.on('data', chunk => {
            if (currentBufferSize === 0) {
                buffer = Buffer.from(chunk);
            } else if (currentBufferSize < bufferSizeMax && (bufferSizeMax % currentBufferSize) > 65536) {
                buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk])
            } else if (currentBufferSize < bufferSizeMax && (bufferSizeMax % currentBufferSize) < 65536) {
                resultBuffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, chunk], bufferSizeMax);
                buffer = Buffer.from(chunk.slice(bufferSizeMax % chunk.length, chunk.length))
                const part = fs.createWriteStream('part' + partNum);
                part.write(resultBuffer);
                console.log('part written');
                partNum++;
                currentBufferSize = 0;
            }

            currentBufferSize += chunk.length;
        });

        fileStream.on('end', () => {
            const part = fs.createWriteStream('part' + partNum);
            part.write(buffer);
            console.log('part written');
        })

        return;
    };
```

The 'data' event is emitted, however the 'end' event is not emitted. Since the 'data' event is emitted, as far as my understanding of node streams goes, the stream is in flowing mode. Since it is in flowing mode, after all the data is consumed it should emit an 'end' event.

Why isn't that happening in my case?